# Can not update Column bound by an Image field in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, imagefield

I have three columns in my Grid view named TweetText, TweetImageUrl and an Column of ImageFied
whose DataImageUrl Field is TweetImageURl. My problem is that When i use the Edit,update feature of grid, I cant edit/update the TweetImageUrl but I can Update TweetText. But when I remove The ImageField Column then I can update the TweetImageUrl Column too. So Can anyone help so that i can Update the TweetImageUrl with ImageField there in Grid Too?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TwitterUserId" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
           PageSize="14" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Approve" runat="server" 
                      CommandName="Approve" 
                      CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                      Text="Approve" />

                  </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TweetText" HeaderText="TweetText" 
                SortExpression="TweetText" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TweetImageUrl" HeaderText="TweetImageUrl"
                SortExpression="TweetImageUrl" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="TweetImageUrl" HeaderText="Images"  ItemStyle-Height = "10px" ItemStyle-Width = "10px"
                    NullImageUrl="~/Admin/ajax-loader.gif">
                </asp:ImageField>
                       </Columns>
            <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
    </asp:GridView>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mistersmartyplantsConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [TwitterData] WHERE [TwitterUserId] = @original_TwitterUserId AND (([TweetId] = @original_TweetId) OR ([TweetId] IS NULL AND @original_TweetId IS NULL)) AND (([TwitterUserName] = @original_TwitterUserName) OR ([TwitterUserName] IS NULL AND @original_TwitterUserName IS NULL)) AND (([TweetText] = @original_TweetText) OR ([TweetText] IS NULL AND @original_TweetText IS NULL)) AND (([TweetImageUrl] = @original_TweetImageUrl) OR ([TweetImageUrl] IS NULL AND @original_TweetImageUrl IS NULL)) AND (([TwitterDate] = @original_TwitterDate) OR ([TwitterDate] IS NULL AND @original_TwitterDate IS NULL))" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [TwitterData] ([TweetId], [TwitterUserId], [TwitterUserName], [TweetText], [TweetImageUrl], [TwitterDate]) VALUES (@TweetId, @TwitterUserId, @TwitterUserName, @TweetText, @TweetImageUrl, @TwitterDate)" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [TweetId], [TwitterUserId], [TwitterUserName], [TweetText], [TweetImageUrl], [TwitterDate] FROM [TwitterData] WHERE ([Approved] = @Approved) ORDER BY [TwitterDate] DESC" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TwitterData] SET [TweetId] = @TweetId, [TwitterUserName] = @TwitterUserName, [TweetText] = @TweetText, [TweetImageUrl] = @TweetImageUrl, [TwitterDate] = @TwitterDate WHERE [TwitterUserId] = @original_TwitterUserId AND (([TweetId] = @original_TweetId) OR ([TweetId] IS NULL AND @original_TweetId IS NULL)) AND (([TwitterUserName] = @original_TwitterUserName) OR ([TwitterUserName] IS NULL AND @original_TwitterUserName IS NULL)) AND (([TweetText] = @original_TweetText) OR ([TweetText] IS NULL AND @original_TweetText IS NULL)) AND (([TweetImageUrl] = @original_TweetImageUrl) OR ([TweetImageUrl] IS NULL AND @original_TweetImageUrl IS NULL)) AND (([TwitterDate] = @original_TwitterDate) OR ([TwitterDate] IS NULL AND @original_TwitterDate IS NULL))">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TwitterUserId" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TweetId" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TwitterUserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TweetText" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TweetImageUrl" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TwitterDate" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="TweetId" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TwitterUserId" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TwitterUserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TweetText" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TweetImageUrl" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TwitterDate" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="No" Name="Approved" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="TweetId" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TwitterUserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TweetText" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TweetImageUrl" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TwitterDate" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TwitterUserId" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TweetId" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TwitterUserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TweetText" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TweetImageUrl" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TwitterDate" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Show us how far you have done. Post some code and html..

Comment: Where is your Code behind source code? I need c#/vb code to debug this..

Comment: I didnt write any code behind as i am using a SqlDataSource and used the edit,update option given with it

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images" ItemStyle-Height="10px" ItemStyle-Width="10px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval(TweetImageUrl) %>' Height="10px" Width="10px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Rather then

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="TweetImageUrl" HeaderText="Images"  ItemStyle-Height = "10px" ItemStyle-Width = "10px" NullImageUrl="~/Admin/ajax-loader.gif"></asp:ImageField>
```

Hope It Helps. Good Luck.